# Skrollr restarts gsap timeline animation

Tags: timeline, skrollr, gsap

Does anybody have any experience in working with skrollr and gsap's timeline?
I have a few animations, and after applying skrollr to the page, with each scroll, the first animation is activated and played from the start.

The script is set to play the animation when reached, and after that it checkes a variable playing so it doesn't start over and over again (I already checked this with console.log and the animation doesn't get restarted there).

The problem is more subtle I fear, so if anyone can shed some light on this matter it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A fiddle would be really helpful. **More importantly** you should consider using another framework. `skrollr` development was ceased more than one year ago. A good alternative is [`ScrollMagic`](http://scrollmagic.io/). It also integrates perfectly with `GreenSock`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately I cant make a fiddle, because there are a lot of factors and I don't know if I can reproduce it, but I will take a look at ScrollMagic.:)